# How to authenticate a user in wordpress [via android]

Tags: android, json, wordpress, xml-rpc

I'm trying to figure out how to authenticate a user via android (java). The app can successfully create a user but I'm not sure I've found any (or at least decent) documentation for the XMLRPC API WordPress has, and I tried the JSON-API AUTH User plugin but I can't figure out how to post anything (can be found here: https://github.com/mattberg/wp-json-api-auth )
I'd appreciate either help on how to use the XMLRPC API or the git hub project or any other method you've found to work.

Comment: does anyone have any advice / direction?

Answer (score 1):

for your question please refer to do for the plugiin JSON-api_auth... http://wordpress.org/support/topic/looking-for-this-in-ages#post-

I hope this help..

Answer (score 0):

To authenticate user , you need authentication cookie that is usually generated once the user has given his/ her credentials to the respective platform the user wants to login same as in the browser . So to do so from android you need wordpress plug in that will help you with this task . example plug in is **Json Api User** . This plugin sits or is installed on top of **JSON Api** plug in . so to have **JSON Api user** installed you need to install first **JSON Api** plugin , then activate it . After that install **JSON Api User** then activate it . From there you can use the following link to generate authentication cookie from your android application .

www.your-domain.com/api/user/generate_auth_cookie/?insecure=cool&username=USER_NAME&password=PASSWORD .

If the user credentials provided are valid , the user will have the the result with status : "ok" then cookie : "SOME CHARACTERS" cookie_name : "SOME CHARACTER" and some other json key-value pair . Else if the credentials provided is not true the status key will have a value of "error" and also you will have an error key with its respective value .